# Add same group of control at run time

Tags: vb.net

I have to add to a usercontrol (VB.NET) a variable group of similar controls.
The context:
For iceskate competition I have to create a userform with n lines (n = number of participant). On each line i have to add m combobox and m textbox (m = number of elements)

I do this in the following code, but for the combobox, when i change one , all the others keeps the same selected item. This is not the same for the textbox. I do not understand why.

Any idea?

```
For I = 1 To  nbrelements
                            Dim cmbelem As ComboBox
                            cmbelem = New ComboBox()
                            cmbelem.DataSource = tblelements
                            cmbelem.ValueMember = "Code"
                            cmbelem.DisplayMember = "Code"
                            cmbelem.Name = "Elem" & I & "/" & dtr.Item("idpatineur")
                            cmbelem.Height = 20
                            cmbelem.Width = 60
                            PosHor += 65
                            cmbelem.Location = new Point(PosHor,posligne)
                            Fempty.Controls.Add(cmbelem)

                            cmbelem = nothing
                            Dim txtElem As TextBox
                            txtElem = New TextBox()
                            txtElem.Name = "txt" & I & "/" & dtr.Item("idpatineur")
                            txtElem.Text = "0"
                            txtElem.Height = 20
                            txtElem.Width = 20
                            PosHor += 65
                            txtelem.Location = new Point(PosHor,posligne)
                            Fempty.Controls.Add(TxtElem)
                        Next
```

Comment: All the CBOs are using the same identical datasource.  what exactly is `tblelements` (what is the type)?

Comment: tblElements is a datatable with all the possible elements (in skating: triple loots, or other skating figure). the type of member is string (eg :3lt for triple loots). The objective is to choice the element done, then give a value in the textbox. There is a variable number of elements depending on another variable (category) that is used to determine nbrelements

Comment: I just find the solution: I add a new binding context cmbelem.bindingContext = new Bindincontext

Comment: Use a `New BindingSource` for each CBO on the same datatable. That doesnt look like an actual `UserControl` they are usually used to *avoid* creating individual control elements like that.  ALso note that a DataGridView could probably be used in place of that

Comment: Thanks for your solution and suggestion. I will also try with datagridview

Comment: That might not work with a varying number of elements - an actual `UserControl` could configure itself.  Maybe start with a full set of control elements and hide/disable those which do not apply to a category passed